# Get custom fields from a custom post type with a shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I have created a custom post type: "products". In this post type there are six custom fields with information automatically imported from WP All Import.

I would like to retrieve the information from those 6 custom fields using a shortcode. Ideally, it would be possible to retrieve the information by using the slug of the post, so (the "code" being the slug):

```
[product code="12345678"]
```

The above should look for the "product" with slug 12345678 and then output the information from those six custom fields.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Attribute value in the `shortcode` and get the custom field values:

```
function product_func($atts) {
    $post_id = $atts['code'];
    $key = "my_custom_field_key";//for 1 field, you can do this 6 times for the 6 values
    $custom_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
    return $custom_value;
}

add_shortcode('product', 'product_func');
```

if you want to debug the post meta field values use this code:

```
function product_func($atts) {
    $post_id = $atts['code'];
    //lets check if we are getting the att
    echo "<h1>THE ATT, SHOULD MATCH THE CODE YOU SEND</h1></br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($post_id);
    echo "</pre>";
    //lets check if we are getting the att
    echo "</br><h1>WE MAKE SURE THE POST IS NOT NULL, MEANING IT SHOULD EXIST</h1></br>";
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($post);
    echo "</pre>";

    //lets check the meta values for the post
    echo "</br><h1>WE LIST ALL META VALUES TO CHECK THE KEY NAME OF THE CUSTOM FIELD WE WANT TO GET</h1></br>";
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($meta);
    echo "</pre>";

    $key = "my_custom_field_key";//for 1 field, you can do this 6 times for the 6 values
    $custom_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
    return $custom_value;
}

add_shortcode('product', 'product_func');
```

it shows each value needed to get the `custom field, should look like this:

[image]

so in my case the key would be:

```
$key = "MY CUSTOM FIELD";
```

Comment: Thank you! But now it returns (in your example) "my_custom_field_key". How do I get the value of the custom field to appear?

Comment: change the `$key` to the name of the one of your 6 custom fields, then do a `var_dump($custom_value);` before the return, show me what that outputs.

Comment: Now I have this:

'function productgids_query_product($atts) {

    $post_id = $atts['ean'];
    
 $key = "media_markt_prijs_EUR";
    $custom_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
 
 var_dump($custom_value);
 
    return $custom_value;

}

add_shortcode('product', 'productgids_query_product');'

Shortcode is:

[product ean="0885909627561"]

Now the output is:

string(0) ""

Comment: i just updated my answer, added code for debugging.